# Perl - Generating Unique Identifiers

Tags: arrays, perl, contains

first of all, I have to admit that I am new to Perl, so my question might seem quite rubish for some you, and I am sorry. I am currently working with the VMWare SDK for Perl and I am stuck on my uploading function. What I would like to do, is generate a unique identifier for each VMDKs (e.g. hard-disks I add to a VM). Basically, the user provides that the hard-disk should have as a parameter of the script.

However, we have a problem if the user choses a name which is already taken. I thought about many solutions, like adding a timestamp (which would be unique), but I would like something more elegant. So, let us consider :

**@vmdks** : List all the hard-disks which are already on the VM

**$filename** : Name that the user wants to give to the VMDK, once it is on the VM

**$target** : Name that the hard-disk will ACTUALLY have.

I would like something like filename-00X, where X is the occurence. So for example, if someone tries to add a hard-disk called "FOO", while one already exists, it will be renamed into "FOO-001". Note that the user can only enter a disk name with Alphanumerical characters, so he cannot name a hard-disk "FOO-001", which avoids conflicts.

So since I do not know Perl very much, I decided to write it in pseudo-code, hope you do not mind :

```
IF $filename IS IN @vmdks
   # So here we have a conflict

   IF $filename-X IS IN @vmdks  
      # X should be a 3-digit number, like 001, 002, 666, etc.
      INDEX := X
      INDEX++
      $target = $filename-INDEX
   ELSE
      $target = $filename-001
   ENDIF
ELSE
   $target = $filename 
ENDIF
```

I guess I can easily do the first condition by something like :

```
if(grep{$_ eq $filename} @vmdks) ...
```

But the second one... I am really stuck :/ How could I match $filename-index, and then retrieve the latter?

Thank you very much, I hope I was clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do the matching using the [smart-match operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator). I've done your pseudo code in Perl with a slight adjustment to your algorithm.

Please note that **There Is More Than One Way To Do It**. You could also use a hash for the lookup. That will be a lost faster, but consume more memory. It depends on the task which is the best choice.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @vmdks = qw( foo bar dilbert dilbert-001 );

sub test_filename {
  my ($filename) = @_;

  # abort if the filename is not alphanumeric
  return if $filename =~ /\W/;

  # check if the filename is in our list
  if ($filename ~~ @vmdks) {
    my $i = 1; # counter, starting at 1
    # check if the extended filename is in the list
    while ( sprintf('%s-%03d', $filename, $i) ~~ @vmdks ) {
      $i++; # increment
    }
    # assign the new filename
    $filename = sprintf('%s-%03d', $filename, $i);
  }

  return $filename;
}

# test ist
for (qw ( phb dilbert foo foo bar dogbert bar foo 1234 123) ) {
  say test_filename($_);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sub-array of all the candidates as:

```
my @tmp = grep(/^$filename-\d+/, @vmdks);
```

and the last element of the `@tmp` would be the latest indexed filename for `$filename`